# How to VNC into current session, instead of creating a new one (from mac)?

Tags: 12.04, remote-desktop, vnc, macosx

I have setup my ubuntu machine to allow remote connections using the default "Desktop Sharing Preferences"  panel, and then I used Mac's VNC viewer Share Screens to connect to it, and it works.

However, it doesn't connect to the current open session in the machine, it creates a new one, which it will then keep using everytime I connect (but if I log in person to the machine, I get the other session, the original one).

This means I can't see/use the windows that I was working with, and some apps like Firefox won't even let me open them, since they say an instance of the program is already open.

Is there a way to VNC directly into the existing/current session instead of creating a new one?

Edit:

This is are my settings:
[image: Desktop Sharing Preferences]

Comment: What VNC server software are you using on Ubuntu? The default 'Desktop Sharing' (aka vino-server) should do exactly what you describe.

Comment: Yeah I'm using the default remote app I'm Ubuntu, and just configuring it to always accept incoming connections with a pin

Comment: Does `vino-server` use the `tightvnc`-like method of starting a new X display? @FranciscoNoriega Do you have both the `Allow other users to...` checkboxes checked?

Comment: @BharadwajRaju, I'm not sure about the first question, regarding the one addressed to me,  yes, I have both  checked. I've updated the original question  with a screenshot of my settings too.

Comment: @FranciscoNoriega Could you try `x11vnc` and see? It requires more manual configuration, but it works.

Comment: I ended up using RDP instead of vnc..